# Django - Edit custom user profile fields in two different forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have a really big headache. I've been searching informations for the whole week and yet I'm still stuck.

I want to create two subpages with 2 different forms yet connected with the same user model:
**/account/register.html** - I'm using Django generic UserCreationForm already
**/account/questionnaire.html** - page for UPDATING additional information such as user city,website,phone etc.

Registration form is working. I have problem with second one.
Console output when I send the second form:

`[25/Apr/2018 17:29:11] "POST /accounts/edituserinfo/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Apr/2018 17:29:11] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1818`

302 means redirect I guess...

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from accounts.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    field_order = ['username', 'email', 'password1','password2',
        'first_name','last_name']

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        }

    def save(self,commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = {
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
        }

class EditUserInfo(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = {
            'description',
            'city',
            'website',
            'phone',
        }
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, redirect, HttpResponse
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm, EditProfileForm, EditUserInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', args)

def edit_user_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserInfo(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditUserInfo(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_user_info.html', args)
```

**register.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
  <title>Register.html</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**edit_user_info.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
  <title>Edit_user_info.html</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit user info</h1>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit User Info</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. When the form is valid, you return a redirect response. That's the `302` response in the console. The browser then loads the new URL (the `200` response in the console. It's not clear what the problem is, isn't that what you want to happen?

Comment: Form seems to be sent correctly but when I look up the admin page nothing is entered to those fields. It's looks like form has never been filled out.

Comment: As I say in my answer below, `instance=request.user` is incorrect.

Comment: the form `EditUserInfo` is absent. where is this form?

Answer (score 0):

The `EditUserInfo` form is for the `UserProfile` model. Therefore you should instantiate it with a `UserProfile` instance, not `request.user` (a `User` instance).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit_user_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserInfo(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        ...
    else:
        form = EditUserInfo(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    ...
```

Note that I've added the `login_required` decorator, so that only logged-in users can access the view.

Comment: I've got an error when I try to put your code to use: `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/edituserinfo/
User has no userprofile.`

Comment: If the user doesn't have a profile that error suggests that your `create_profile` signal isn't working. You can either fix your code/database so that the user always has a profile, or you can create the profile in the view, e.g. `profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)`.